# Create Local Notification on iphone

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am trying to create a local Notification button like "Are you sure you want to delete yes or no? How would I go about doing this

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Are you sure you want to delete?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", @"No", nil];
 alert.tag=1;
 [alert show];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag==1)
    {
       if(buttonIndex==0)
       {
             //Do when click "Yes" button
       }
       else if(buttonIndex==1)
       {
             //Do when click "No" button
       }
   }
}
```

may be it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are trying to accomplish, I do not think you want to use a UILocalNotification, looks like what you want is a [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My title" message:@"Are you sure you want to delete?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", @"No", nil];
[alert show];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I wanted. How would I then add actions to the buttons?

Comment: @matthewmoss set a UIAlertViewDelegate

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UIAlertView` for what you want to do, just like Oscar Gomez says.

To add actions to the buttons first implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` and use the method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

You can check the `buttonIndex` and perform the appropriate action, ( index 0 for button 
"Yes" and 1 for button "No").

Answer (score 0):

This code block in AppDelegate file :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

// This code block is invoked when application is in foreground (active-mode) 
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    **UIAlertView *notificationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@“Alert” message:@“Are you sure you want to delete?” delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@“Yes”,@“No”, nil];

     notificationAlert.tag = 101;
    [notificationAlert show];**
   // NSLog(@"didReceiveLocalNotification");
}

**- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if(alertView.tag==1) {
        if(buttonIndex==0)
        {
            //Do when click "Yes" button
        }
        else if(buttonIndex==1)
        {
            //Do when click "No" button
        }
    }
}**
```

This code block in .m file of any ViewController :

```
-(IBAction)startLocalNotification {  // Bind this method to UIButton action
    NSLog(@"startLocalNotification");

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:7];
    notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];    
}
```

The above code display an AlertView after time interval of 7 seconds when pressed on button that binds “startLocalNotification”.
If application is in background then it displays BadgeNumber as 10 and with default notification sound.